# How to import a DXF to blender 2.8 correctly?

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves

I want to build a indoor map in web, and what I have is only a Autocad dwg file .
My proposal is as follows :
1 in AutoCAD , I explode all objects ,Save dwg file as dxf file
2 Import dxf file in blender
3 convert all curve to mesh
4 export the mesh as glb file
5 import the glb file and render in threejs

here is my questions ,any suggestions is appreciate.
1. my dxf is  [image: the auto cad file image]
after import dxf in blender 2.8,it looks as follows
[image: the blender shows image]

why so many unnecessary line/curves ? 
how to remove those ?

2. it seems lots of lines is in one curve ,
   when I select on line ,the blender  hilight  many lines/curves .
   how to split it one to one ? (I explode all objects in AutoCAD)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After i delete all arcs whose angle less than 90 degrees (include all round) and all oval,
all the  unnecessary line/curves is not shown in blender .
I don't konw why

[image]

Answer (score 0):

here is my work around:

CAD to .dxf - > .dxf to inksacpe - > inksacpe to .svg > .svg to blender

make sure the scale is correct when import/export

Answer (score 0):

this lines are dots.

you can make them in ACAD visible with ddptyp

[image]

Comment: refer https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-8B7AB3E2-B9D0-49FB-97AE-9183CE0E80AA-htm.html  ddptyp is Obsolete. Executes the PTYPE command. anyway ,thanks for your reply